# Convert static method to lambda in PHP

Tags: php, reflection, lambda

I want to get static method from class and copy it to variable.

This is non-working example illustrating my question:

```
class foo
{
    public static function bar($argument){ return 2*$argument; }
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('foo');
// here is no ReflectionMethod::getClosure() method in reality
$lambda = $class->getMethod('bar')->getClosure();

echo $lambda(3);
```

So my question: is this possible by any normal way? I find only one way for now. I can parse source file, get method source from it and convert it using create_function() but it's too perverse.

Comment: I'm not sure you can using reflection: I think you'd need to use the PHP tokenizer

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of this, but what about create the lambda function as a wrapper to `foo::bar()`?

Comment: After thinking a while I dare to say that it _should_ be impossible to convert a class method into a lambda function. It does not make sense, if it would be possible (or is, we are talking about php with all its problems here...), then things might really break. The reason is that the class method might not be independant: it might refer to other methods or members of the class. Without these being present the lamba function certainly would make no sense at all...

Comment: Thanks for answers but you are right, arkascha: I tried to be independant of the class definition. So wrapping static call inside of closure is answer for my question but not solution for my problem.

Comment: @crimaniak, what is your problem?

Comment: arkascha: Your last comment is really best answer, thanks!

Comment: @sectus, I tried to collect some static methods from set of classes and make some manipulations on it to speedup more late usage but now I understand it was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it with closure.

```
$lamda = function($argument){return foo::bar($argument);};
```

Or you can try to use something like this

```
function staticMethodToClosure($class, $method) {
    return function($argument)use($class, $method){return $class::$method($argument);};
}
```

Comment: See my earlier comment above... However I guess the OP wants to be independant of the class definition.

Comment: @arkascha, new function there.

Comment: What is that meant to make as a difference? You still need the class definition. Nothing has changed, except that you allow to specify class and method name. Big deal.

Answer (score 0):

An array in the format `array($className, $methodName)` is invokable as a static method call so this may work for you.

```
class foo
{
    public static function bar($argument){ return 2*$argument; }
    public static function getStaticFunction($arg){
        return array("foo", $arg);
    } 
}

$a = foo::getStaticFunction("bar");
echo $a(5);  // echos 10
```